# Classes defined in CoffeeScript not found by Jasmine specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, jasmine

I am building a backbone.js app on a Rails 3.1 back-end.  I'm using CoffeeScript to write the backbone classes, and Jasmine (via jasmine-headless-webkit) for testing.

Given the following (partial) tree:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   │       ├── avia_view.js.coffee
├── spec
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── views
│   │       └── avia_view_spec.js.coffee
```

... I would expect `avia_view_spec.js.coffee` to know about `Avia.AviaView`, which is defined in `avia_view.js.coffee`.

However, I get the following output from running `bundle exec jasmine-headless-webkit`:

```
Running Jasmine specs...
F

Avia.AviaView render creates a new MatricesView . (/home/duncan/avia/spec/javascripts/views/avia_view_spec.js.coffee:10)
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Avia in /home/duncan/avia/spec/javascripts/views/avia_view_spec.js.coffee (line ~5)
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Avia in /home/duncan/avia/spec/javascripts/views/avia_view_spec.js.coffee (line ~10)
```

My `jasmine.yml` contains the following:

```
src_files:
  - public/javascripts/prototype.js
  - public/javascripts/effects.js
  - public/javascripts/controls.js
  - public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
  - public/javascripts/application.js
  - public/javascripts/**/*.js
```

I *think* I need to tell Jasmine to load the contents of `avia_view.js.coffee` but I'm not entirely sure how.  Adding an explicit reference in the `src_files` section in `jasmine.yml` doesn't seem to make a difference ...

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I suspect it's something simple ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having seen to much of your code, I'd suspect it beacuse of CoffeeScript's function wrapping ([docs](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#lexical_scope)). You need to ensure that all the symbols you want to use are exported to somewhere you can get at them ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables) is a thorough discussion about that).

**Edit:** [here's](http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/SmoothCoffeeScript.html#toc-Chapter-11) another longish and theoretical but good documentation on this topic.

Comment: That was one of the problems; I define my Avia 'namespace' in a .js file that I hadn't included.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your `avia_view.js.coffee`

```
(exports ? this).Avia = Avia
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548445/coffeescript-unit-testing-global-variables) for a detailed explanation.

Alternatively try [this](http://www.derekhammer.com/2012/02/18/testing-coffeescript-for-rails-with-jasmine.html);

```
window.Avia = Avia
```

We encountered the same problem; I highly recommend [JasmineRice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice)