# Testing CS classes in the browser with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, tdd, coffeescript, mocha.js

What's the convention for making my mocha tests aware of my class under test (for running Mocha in the browser)? Since both are wrapped in closures, neither is in the global scope...

[image: Can't find the Monkey class due to the fact it's not global, I think...]

---

**monkey.spec.coffee**

```
describe "Monkey", ->
  it "adds two to the given number", ->
    expect Monkey.add2(4).to.equal(6)
```

**monkey.coffee**

```
class Monkey
```

**test_runner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mocha Test Runner</title>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css">
    <script src="mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="expect.js"></script>
    <script>
      mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>

    <!-- Load in files under test -->
    <script src="monkey.js"></script>

    <!-- Load in spec files -->
    <script src="monkey.spec.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script>
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classes defined in CoffeeScript not found by Jasmine specs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310329/classes-defined-in-coffeescript-not-found-by-jasmine-specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Monkey
```

creates a `Monkey` class that's scoped within the file. You want

```
class window.Monkey
```

or

```
class @Monkey
```

for short.

Comment: Won't that have the effect of making `Monkey` global? I don't necessarily want `Monkey` to be global, but I do want my tests to know of its existence... or am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: Because browser-based JavaScript doesn't have a linker, the only way to make variables visible outside of a single file (given that each file has a wrapper) is to make it visible everywhere. You could add code to, say, only export `Monkey` if you're in test mode.